# SLI Video Cards

Tags: pci-express, graphics-card

I'm configuring a new desktop. I'm looking through all PCI Express 2.0 x16 video cards on NewEgg at the moment. All cards seem to be stating that they have SLI Support or CrossFireX support. I know that these 2 technologies enable you to connect more than one video card together to create more of a powerful video experience. These cards that have this support seem to be more expensive that other cards though. When I did a NewEgg search for cards that did NOT have these two supports, no matches came up for PCI Express 2.0 x16 (haven't checked other interfaces yet though).

Can you run an SLI/CrossFireX card as a single card (and if you can is it efficient or even good?), or do you need to have more than one card to run them? Also, do they make cards without these two technologies anymore, and are they even cheaper at this point? I really have no need for SLI/CrossFireX at all, so I was wondering what I should look into.

Do cards without this technology not run on the PCI Express 2.0 x16 interface?

Thanks ahead of time for all your help.

Comment: I'm voting to move this to SuperUser; no doubt others will too. Please don't double-post this there; the migration will handle that, you link a new account to your existing one, and Bob's your uncle.

Comment: So all I have to do is create a SuperUser account with the same OpenId and everything happens automatically? Where will I go to check for answers, this post or the other one?

Comment: Once it gets migrated there will be a link here to the migrated question. You can check for answers there on Super User. Please read the FAQs on both sites so you'll know which types of questions each site is geared towards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what grade of cards you are looking for, there should be cards available with SLI/CrossFireX although I think all high-end graphics cards these day come with SLI/CrossFireX.

It shouldn't be a problem to run a single SLI/CrossFireX card, it's just an optional interface.